# Can I read from the AppEngine BlobStore using the remote api

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to read (and subsequently save) blobs from the blobstore using the remote api.  I get the error: `"No api proxy found for service "blobstore""` when I execute the read.
Here is the stub code:

```
    for b in bs.BlobInfo.all().fetch(100):
        blob_reader = bs.BlobReader(str(b.key))
        file = blob_reader.read()
```

the error occurs on the line: `file = blob_reader.read()`
I am reading the file from my personal appspot via terminal with:

```
python tools/remote_api/blobstore_download.py --servername=myinstance.appspot.com --appid=myinstance
```

So, reading from the blobstore possible via the remote api? or is my code bad?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We recently added blobstore support to remote_api. Make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK, and your error should go away.

Comment: Yes, that was the deal, we had the latest version, but some other code that I was unaware of was directing to an older version.  Thanks for your help.